# get index failed using es2015 map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

```
{map(arr, (obj,index) => 
  <div key={index}>{obj.name}</div>
</div>)}
```

What's wrong with my jsx above? couldn't get the index using map?

Comment: Define "failed", what are you actually getting as the index? What do you see that makes you say it is broken.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the proper way to use map.

```
array.map((x, index)=>{
     return (<div key={index}>{x.name}</div>);
});
```

or

```
Array.prototype.map.call(arr, function(x, index) {
    return (<div key={index}>{x.name}</div>);
});
```

Mozilla

[Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=control)

Comment: Presumably they are using Lodash's `map` or something?

Answer (score 0):

You are not wrapping your JSX content within  `()` . Also you need to have the `(` on the same line as `=>` and you have an extra closing `div`

```
{map(arr, (obj,index) => (
  <div key={index}>{obj.name}</div>
))}
```

Comment: Those parens are not required.